# problems while formating to fat32

Tags: partitioning, external-hdd, gparted, fat32

I need to format my external hard drive to fat32 in order for it to work on a ps3, but when i try to do it in Gparted I get an error :

[image]

if this helps, first I formated it to fat32 without any problems but when I started transferring files I got an input/output error and every file turned into read only, so I remounted the drive and started transferring again and the same thing happened.

Comment: Maybe something chokes on the empty volume label. Does it work if you issue the displayed command directly and without setting a label like so: `sudo mkdosfs -F32 -v -I /dev/sdb2`?

Comment: What size is the Drive?  What size are the files you're trying to copy?

Comment: the files size is less than 4GB ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I formated the whole disk to ext4 then retried and it worked with no problems so far, I think what caused this problem is that I tried to emulate a BD using the same hard disk that contains games.