# GParted won't format FAT32 partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-formatting

I get this error when attempting to create a FAT32 partition with GParted:

```
mkdosfs: failed whilst writing FAT
```

I've tried creating a new partition table first, wiping the drive (with 0's), and [formatting it ext2-4 before making it fat32](https://askubuntu.com/q/378374/48659). No dice.

Here are screenshots showing the error and drive information:

[image: Error]

[image: Device info]

I'm getting a lot of questions in comments. Let me try to answer all of those and preempt more.

- The drive was previously a Mac OS X 'Time Machine' Backup drive, and was thus formatted with HFS+ with a GPT. This should not matter since I *physically* (as opposed to *logically*) wiped the drive with `\x00`'s.
- I have tried running the command manually without using GParted, I get the same error displayed in the above screenshot.
- The drive is a USB-powered portable drive (you can see more details in the drive information screenshot).
- I have (and am using) root permissions.
- I installed the latest version of GParted using the package manager.
- **I am open to alternate solutions for formatting this drive as FAT32 that do not use GParted or mkdosfs. The end goal is to format the drive.**

Comment: have you tried something related to "sudo mkdosfs -F32 -v -I /dev/sdb2"

Comment: It is unmounted, and @Sushantp606 yes. I get the same error regardless of whether I run the command myself or GParted does it for me.

Comment: Did you remove linux swap? (Swapoff)

Comment: @samgabbay it never had one - it was formerly HFS+ formatted with a GPT - but that should not matter now since it has been physically wiped and a new MBR partition table created

Comment: If mkdosfs is reporting an error, then likely it is experiencing difficulty writing to a portion of the drive.  You might try formatting the drive from another operating system such as Windows.  However if the drive is beginning to fail, then I would expect this to fail too.

Answer (score 1):

With a size of nearly 1 TiB this disk is scratching on the very limits of the FAT32 file system. FAT32 is able to support up to 1 TiB, but only with a cluster size of 32 KiB.

It seems that GParted or rather `mkdosfs` is trying for a cluster size of `32 * 512 B = 16384 = 16 KiB`.

Try calling `mkdosfs` from a terminal like this:

```
mkdosfs -F32 -v -n "" -s 64 -S 512 /dev/sdc1
```

This tells `mkdosfs` to use 64 sectors of size 512 B for a cluster.